# Inkscape pdf to svg conversion messes with math in pdf

Tags: pdf, svg, inkscape

I tried to convert a pdf generated by latex (can be found on [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yz6sihu86kfraip/mylatex-crop.pdf?dl=1)) to an svg using inkscape 0.91 using the command `inkscape --without-gui --file=mylatex-crop.pdf --export-plain-svg=out-01.svg`. However, the math in the output ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/371ehv29/)) looks messy. Does anyone know what the problem here is? Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm trying to transfer some PDF files to my Kobo reader with proper math formulas, as the reader doesn't handle mathjax nor MathML...

Comment: No, didn't find anything, but also didn't go out of my way looking.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Inkscape and there is an online service you can try instead: https://cloudconvert.com/pdf-to-svg

It uses either Inkscape or muPDF and muPDF turned out to actually generate "proper" math symbols from LaTeX PDF's. Although in my test the generated SVG-files are 4x as big as the original PDF (a math paper).

[image]